# Definition of syscall() functions?

Tags: linux, system-calls

I have a code that uses syscall() function to directly call to linux system call

```
__ret = syscall(NR, ##__VA_ARGS__);
```

This return error ENOSYS. I want to trace what syscall() function does and what it called into to find why it return that result. I searched around but haven't found definition for it.

For more information, I run this on linux 4.1 for arm64

Comment: What are the values of `NR` and `##__VA_ARGS__` when you receive the `ENOSYS` error? `NR` I am more interested in since `ENOSYS` suggests it is not implemented.

Comment: __NR_bdflush here. I know this is deprecated but here I want know where this is checked in syscall() or in which called from that. So why I ask for definition of syscall().